# How does Java's Stream.distinct() select which of the duplicates to use

Tags: java, java-stream, distinct, hashcode

In Java let's say I have a class called Person. It has four properties:

1. Long personId
2. String name
3. int age
4. List<String> petNames

Let's say I have an array list variable of people called peopleList:

1. personId: 1, name: "Tim", age: 28, petNames: [Brix]
2. personId: 1, name: "Tim", age: 28, petNames: [Brix, Cowboy]
3. personId: 1, name: "Tim", age: 28, petNames: [Brix, Cowboy, Fido]
4. personId: 2, name: "Jamie", age: 19, petNames: []
5. personId: 3, name: "Fred", age: 23, petNames: []

I override hashCode and equals of Person class to be this:

```java
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + personId.intValue();
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    System.out.println("Person equals method");
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (personId != other.personId)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

And then I use `peopleList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());` to remove duplicates. I was originally wrong, turns out it selects the first occurrence of Tim which is having only one pet and not the instance with all three pets. My original question though is: **Which instance does distinct() choose?** And that has been answered below.

Comment: From the _javadoc_ of method [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) in class `java.lang.Object`: _equal objects must have equal hash codes_

Comment: Thanks Abra for helping, can you expand on that a little?

Comment: [*What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/642706)

Comment: **Caution:** `if (personId != other.personId)` will fail for most Number instances.  Always compare objects using the `equals` method.  If one or both of them might be null, use [Objects.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 2):

## `distinct` uses `equals` method

Did you read the documentation, the Javadoc for [`Stream#distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct())? Programming by documentation usually works better than programming by intuition.

The first sentence says:

> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to Object.equals(Object)) of this stream.

Did you override the `equals` method? An edit to your Question says you did indeed.

In your `equals` method, you compare only the member field `personId`, of type `Long`. So why would you expect the list of pet names to be considered?

Similarly, if the three `Tim` objects have different ages such as 28, 48, and 98, that too is irrelevant. Your code says to consider them to be the same as long as the `personId` number is the same.

You told the JVM to examine only the id field. So if two `Person` objects have the same 64-bit integer number in their `personId` field, they are considered equal. If the two numbers differ, the two `Person` objects are not equal.

As to your more general question about which of two or more equal objects encountered in the stream are kept as the result of `distinct`: Again, read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()).

> For ordered streams, the selection of distinct elements is stable (for duplicated elements, the element appearing first in the encounter order is preserved.) For unordered streams, no stability guarantees are made.

So:

- If you have an ordered stream, the first object wins. Any duplicate objects that follow are eliminated.
- If the stream is not ordered, then any of the objects may win. You should not depend on any particular one to win.

You do not disclose what kind of stream you are using. So we cannot know if it is ordered or not. So we can provide no further insight.

## `equals` & `hashCode` must share same logic

The implementations of `equals` and `hashCode` should always use the same logic. The  `hashCode` method should always be overridden along with `equals` to maintain the general contract between them, which is: *equal objects must have equal hash codes.*

If for equality you compare the `personId` field, then your hash code should be based on the `personId` field value.

You did this correctly in your code. But, you could do so more simply by using `Objects.hash( this.id )`. See this alternate implementation of your code.

```java
package work.basil.example.distinct;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class Person
{
    private final Long id;
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final List < String > petNames;

    public Person ( Long id , String name , int age , List < String > petNames )
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.petNames = petNames;
    }

    public Long id ( ) { return id; }

    public String name ( ) { return name; }

    public int age ( ) { return age; }

    public List < String > petNames ( ) { return petNames; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( final Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) { return true; }
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) { return false; }
        Person person = ( Person ) o;
        return id.equals( person.id );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( this.id );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Person[" +
                "id=" + this.id + ", " +
                "name=" + this.name + ", " +
                "age=" + this.age + ", " +
                "petNames=" + this.petNames + ']';
    }
}
```

The issue of `equals` and `hashCode` needing to share the same logic is covered in the documentation, in the Java literature, and on Stack Overflow extensively. Search to learn more. Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/642706).

## Example

Here is an example app using that class above.

```java
package work.basil.example.distinct;

import java.util.List;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        List < Person > persons =
                List.of(
                        new Person( 1L , "Tim" , 28 , List.of( "Brix" ) ) ,
                        new Person( 1L , "Tim" , 28 , List.of( "Brix" , "Cowboy" ) ) ,
                        new Person( 1L , "Tim" , 28 , List.of( "Brix" , "Cowboy" , "Fido" ) ) ,
                        new Person( 2L , "Jamie" , 19 , List.of() ) ,
                        new Person( 3L , "Fred" , 23 , List.of() )
                );
        List < Person > personsDistinct = persons.stream().distinct().toList();

        System.out.println( "persons = " + persons );
        System.out.println( "personsDistinct = " + personsDistinct );
    }
}
```

When run:

> persons = [Person[id=1, name=Tim, age=28, petNames=[Brix]], Person[id=1, name=Tim, age=28, petNames=[Brix, Cowboy]], Person[id=1, name=Tim, age=28, petNames=[Brix, Cowboy, Fido]], Person[id=2, name=Jamie, age=19, petNames=[]], Person[id=3, name=Fred, age=23, petNames=[]]]
>
> personsDistinct = [Person[id=1, name=Tim, age=28, petNames=[Brix]], Person[id=2, name=Jamie, age=19, petNames=[]], Person[id=3, name=Fred, age=23, petNames=[]]]

## `record`

Tip: If you want **all the member fields to be considered automatically** for `equals` & `hashCode`, and the main purpose of your class is to **communicate data transparently and immutably,** define your class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

In a record, by default, the compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

Furthermore, you can define a record locally as well as define it as a nested class or as a separate class.

```java
record Person( Long id , String name , int age , List < String > petNames ) { }
```

Comment: I thought my hashCode is based on the personId field... can you tell me how it is not?
More importantly, since it looks like it chooses the instance either by first if ordered or randomly if unordered, then how can I specify stream().distinct() to choose the instance with the most pets so that I can always get a consistent result?

Comment: @Adam Oops, I misread your `hashCode`. I'm working on some more example code, then I will edit that section.

Comment: Okay thanks Basil. And regarding this: "You do not disclose what kind of stream you are using." I am using java.util.stream, if that helps answer? To be more specific, I am using hibernate, and fetching a DTO projection with a To Many Association, where I use tuples, and use resultList.stream().map(<lot's of code>).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()).  Basically what this guy did at 2:05: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oTH_Slettc

Comment: @Adam Be careful with names. [`java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) is a package, not a class/interface. You meant [`java.util.stream.Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Comment: @Adam Furthermore, `Stream` is an interface, not a concrete class. Your code must use, directly or indirectly, a concrete class that implements that interface. It is up to you to know if that implementation in "ordered" or not, per the Javadoc discussed above, if you want to know which of the multiple equal objects will be chosen by the `distinct` method.

Comment: Thank you Basil. Can you point me in the direction of how to make the distinct method choose the instance with the most pets?

Comment: @Adam Your last Comment makes no sense. If the size of `petNames` matters, then the three objects with a `personId` of `1` are *not* equal. So calling `distinct` is no longer relevant or useful. You *could* work on ensuring the stream is ordered, with ordering first by `personId` and then by the size of `petNames` to put first the `Person` object with the longest `petNames`. But I suspect at this point we have ventured into an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I am querying my database and have a join, and i have more fields in the data tables than what I want for this particular server response, and so I am using data transfer objects. I am selecting only the 4 fields: person_id, name, age, and pets which is the join to my PETS table. As a result I have 5 rows returned, and my code, which I am leaving out of this post, is creating those three instances for Tim, and I want to only get the last instance that has all three pets added to his pets array. Curious why distinct was recommended for this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oTH_Slettc

Comment: Very good coverage! Instead of saying, *The implementations of `equals` and `hashCode` should always use the same logic.*, I would say, *The  `hashCode` method should always be overridden along with `equals` to maintain the general contract between them, which is: equal objects must have equal hash codes.*.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thank you. I copy-pasted your well-said sentence.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to implement the 'Comparable' interface and use `stream.sorted()` to sort the `list.size()` in the first place

Code Example

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
```

override `compareTo` method

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person person) {
    if (this.getPersonId().equals(person.getPersonId())) {
        if (person.getPetNames().size() > this.getPetNames().size()) {
            return 1;
        } else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

finally

```
peopleList.stream().sorted().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

thanks

Comment: The bottom stream distinct layer uses HashSet for duplicate processing, and HashSet itself is weighted based on HashMap

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment, I was trying to edit it. This is my edited comment: How do I know my stream is ordered? Sure the instances within are ordered thanks to the sorted method, but is that all this means or is there something else that specifies it such that each insertion of the stream is inserted with order?

Comment: Can you expand on that a little? Or give me a link or two to read on what you are saying? Thank you! Very interesting!

Comment: [trying-to-understand-distinct-for-streams-in-java8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562359/trying-to-understand-distinct-for-streams-in-java8)  Maybe this article will help you

Comment: This `compareTo` method is broken. Even if you fix the method, it’s a strongly discouraged idea, to have a natural order that contradicts equality. For example, since your `compareTo` method says that all objects with different ids are equal, the `sorted().distinct()` approach can remove arbitrary elements if an element with a different id exists.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. It seems that my method still needs to be discussed. Please forgive me for not understanding what you said
`the sorted().distinct() approach can remove arbitrary elements if an element with a different id exists.`
How does this work, or under what circumstances, can you be more specific? thank you